# form_open action URL is wrong

Tags: php, codeigniter

have this code

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/method'); ?>
```

and it supposed to create this code

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="http://localhost/codeigniter/controller/method">
```

but it created

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="http://localhost/codeigniter/?controller/method">
```

There is an extra ”?” before the controller name.

How can fix that problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your base URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if you set enable_query_strings to TRUE

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: This appears to be the correct reason. Here's a comment from the config.php file (probably in the user guide as well): `Please note that some of the helpers won't work as expected when this feature is enabled, since CodeIgniter is designed primarily to use segment based URLs.` They're talking about _enable_query_strings_